# Problem with sending proxied POST request nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Get an error **Client network socket disconnected before secure error TLS connection was established** 
when sending a POST request through a proxy. I tried different forms, old versions of node and different proxies, but it did not help. Who faced with this please help :3

```
    request.post('https://b.utair.ru/api/v1/login/',
    {
    path: '/',
    agent: agent,
    timeout: 1500000,
    maxRedirects: 10,
    form: {'login':phone},
    json: true,
    headers: {
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5','Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Host':'b.utair.ru','origin':'https://www.utair.ru','Referer':'https://www.utair.ru/'}
},
    function  (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error);
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        console.log('body:', body);
    }
);
```

Comment: Have you tried different http clients? Maybe this is a server problem.

Comment: Which one u recommend? Cause I used https-proxy-agent